# Something went wrong while installing sample data. Please check var/log/system.log for details during Magento installation

Tags: php, magento2

I am a beginner in **Magento**. When i was trying to install **"Magento-CE-2.0.0+Samples-2015-11-17-06-11-18.zip"** on my local server using **Wamp**,it first gets stuck at 90%, after quite a while, it shows *"Success"* but at the end of the page it shows the following error-

> "Something went wrong while installing sample data. Please check
>   var/log/system.log for details. You can retry installing the data now
>   or just start using Magento"

I checked the **"var/log/system.log**" and there is this message-

> [2015-12-21 09:42:48] main.ERROR: Sample Data error: Warning:
>   IntlDateFormatter::parse(): Date parsing failed in
>   C:\wamp\www\Magento\vendor\magento\framework\Stdlib\DateTime\Timezone.php
>   on line 166 [] []

when i click at the button *"Launch Magento Admin"* which is situated at the bottom of the page, i get this error

[image]

> What can i do to solve this problem?

I have already posted it on "Stack Overflow" because i didn't know this forum exists. There is no answer on "Stack Overflow" so i have posted it here again.

Comment: Check if you can access `Magento/index.php/admin_s9y9z4/

Comment: I can not access that @ Alex Paliarush

Answer (score 2):

I could not find a solution for date parsing issue yet. But as per sample data installing you can try below commands from your installation directory.

```
php bin/magento sampledata:deploy
php bin/magento setup:upgrade
```

then compile if required

```
php bin/magento setup:di:compile
```

Answer (score 0):

Many people are facing different problems while installing Magento 2 with sample data. I would suggest try installing Magento without sample data and see if error exists.

Before beginning, make sure you have these on-hand for Magento 2 installation because this may cause an error as well:

Apache Version 2.2 or 2.4, PHP Version 5.5.x or 5.6.x & MySQL Version 5.6x.

Comment: isn't that the right way to install with sample data?how do i add sample data after installation? @Muhammad Fayyaz-Ud-Din Khattak

Comment: @Arif try to install Magento first and then sample data as described in the last section here http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/install-gde/install/sample-data-after-magento.html

Comment: @Arif as described by Alex, you can install sample data by using command line. See the attached link.

Comment: setup successfull but http://localhost/Magento-CE-2.0.0/admin_1u0ow0/ still hast 404 Not Found error.
http://localhost/Magento-CE-2.0.0/index.php/admin_1u0ow0/ also isn't working. @Alex Paliarush @ Muhammad Fayyaz-Ud-Din Khattak

Comment: A common mistake is to not enable [Apache server rewrites](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/install-gde/prereq/apache.html#apache-help-rewrite). Try that and see if your pages render. Also try clearing var/cache and var/page_cache directories.

Comment: it works, although i have faced this webpage has a redirect loop problem and solved it :)

Comment: @Arif good to hear about it :)